# Thread guard for a variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, critical-section

I want to use a variable across multiple threads. To safeguard simultaneous access to that variable, i would like to add a mutex for that variable. But mutex and critical section better suited for piece of code. In case of a variable, it looked ugly to place lock and unlock code everywhere the variable is used. Is there any other simpler way than mutex and critical section?

Answer (score 1):

If it's one variable that you want to protect then use std::atomic (if you are using c++11) or boost::atomic if not.

If it's multiple shared variables in the critical section then you'd need to be careful of cache coherency issues. So I'd use mutexes in that case arround the critical section